# Why does this site use a solid color background image instead of background-color hex code?

Tags: css, background-image, background-color

What is the benefit or reason for using a solid background color image insteade of the css style background-color?

I saw this site http://www.shouldigoout.com/indexa.html using a solid background image from http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/ what would be some reasons for doing this?

Comment: I think there is no reason to use a solid image instead of a css, unless you don't know how to write the css to fit the page....

Comment: Tbh I'm not quite sure why that site is using an image rather than the hex colour value. I have never done that and I wouldn't recommend it either, it's just more work than needed and creating unnecessary http requests to the server to grab the images.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't see any reason why either which is why I was confused they did it. I had thought it might be for something I didn't know about. Cheers to all who replied.

Answer (score 0):

Is this spam advertising the website?

There's really no good reason for this.  I want to try to be charitable, but my guess is the developer just doesn't know what they're doing.  80kb for a 2880 × 1800 solid color background?  If they had some valid reason (a method of tracking?  1x1 images are/were commonly used for silent tracking), at least it would be smaller and tiled.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any benefit at all, in fact you are adding one asset that needs to be loaded which will have a impact on the loading time of the website.